# A recursion in a sum

Tags: recursion

I wish to use a recursion to continue the updating n2, n3, etc., up to n30. Probably simple concept for an experienced MM user. Sorry.

```
nquanta[\[Delta]_] := Tan[Pi/4 + \[Delta]]^2
n2[\[Delta]_] = nquanta[\[Delta]] + Tan[Pi/4 + \[Delta]]^2
n3[\[Delta]_] = n2[\[Delta]] + Tan[Pi/4 + \[Delta]]^2
```

The functional form I chose above is somewhat arbitrary. Also, 0<Delta<<Pi/4, i.e., a small positive constant so tangent is well-defined in first polar quadrant. I have found a solution using "Which" but I'm told this is not an ideal approach so I've deleted a secondary comment to that effect.

Comment: Use NestList , for example nquanta[\[Delta]_] := Tan[Pi/4 + \[Delta]]^2   
nq[i_, \[Delta]_] := 
 NestList[# + nquanta[\[Delta]] &, nquanta[\[Delta]], i - 1]

Comment: I think I must not be grokking the question. Isn't this just multiplication? I.e. n3[d] is really just 3*nquanta[d].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)
```

Use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) or [`RSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) for a closed form

```
Clear[nquanta];
nquanta[n_, δ_] = 
 RSolveValue[{nquanta[n, δ] == 
     nquanta[n - 1, δ] + Tan[Pi/4 + δ]^2,
    nquanta[1, δ] == Tan[Pi/4 + δ]^2}, nquanta[n, δ], 
   n] // FullSimplify

(* n (-1 + 2/(Cos[δ] - Sin[δ])^2) *)
```

The function is discontinuous at

```
Solve[{Cos[δ] == Sin[δ], 
   0 <= δ <= 2 Pi}, δ] // Simplify

(* {{δ -> π/4}, {δ -> (5 π)/4}} *)
```

Compare with [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) for integer values of `n`

```
m = 10;
And @@ Thread[
   (nquanta[#, δ] & /@ Range[m]) ==
    NestList[# + Tan[Pi/4 + δ]^2 &, Tan[Pi/4 + δ]^2, 
     m - 1]] // Simplify

(* True *)

Plot3D[nquanta[n, δ], {n, 0, 5}, {δ, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> All,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {n, δ, nquanta})]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[nquanta[n, δ], {n, 0, 5}, {δ, Pi/4, 5 Pi/4},
 PlotRange -> {0, 10},
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {n, δ, nquanta})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bob ... using NestList is very nice solution but I see I will need to learn the syntax of shortcut commands in MM such as "@ &&" and "& /@". I also found on youtube a solution the Which command but can't post it in this comment for some reason.